# DJISDK iOS Flysafe bundle not loading

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

Getting a new error where the DJIFlySafe.bundle is not loading in our app, subsequently causing the product (device) to not connect.

```
inside viewDidAppear: about to register App =========================
2018-10-21 22:06:42.400893-0500 Drone001[373:22220] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x105654820 </var/containers/Bundle/Application/79120C80-0D9F-4EEA-ABBB-46802DFF5EBA/Drone001.app/Frameworks/DJISDK.framework/DJIFlySafe.bundle> (not loaded)
RAW:  activation 255 and bindingState is 255
```

Anyone else ever have this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no impact on product connect. Thanks for the feedback.